# как записать сумму полей в в базу mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Проблема: не могу передать ответ в MySQL таблицу по нажатию на кнопку.

```html
<td class="center"><?php echo $v1_1_1=(round((($v1_1['coun']/$id['coun'])*100),1)) ?>%</td>
```

Мне нужно передавать данные которые php посчитал и вывел. К примеру есть таблица mysql, в таблице 2 поля t1=(2) и t2=(2). PHP считает это t1+t2=t3 и записывает ответ в html таблицу. И вот эту t3 мне нужно передать в другую таблицу mysql

Comment: как я понимаю, вам нужно впистаь оброботчик дял подключения к MySQL и пользоваться соответсвующими функциями , думаю вот этот [материал](http://website-create.ru/web-yroki/sozdanie-saitov-yroki/29-vstavka-dannih-mysql.html) вам поможет

Comment: @Alex.B Плохой материал. Функции mysql_* устарели с версии  5.5 и удалены из версии 7.0

Comment: @E_p, а я и не утверждаю, что это отличный материал, но для решения поставленно задачи вполне. Если так подумать кто в 2016 в здравом уме будет php   пользоваться.